# How to flatten the following nested if let and if statements?

Tags: rust

I'm "normalizing" a string, then using it to search a normalized version of a filename:

```
use glob::glob;

fn main() {
    let text = "Hello：world-    This   is  a  test   string._,\"";
    let normalized = normalize(text);
    let pattern = "/home/alex/Downloads/papers/*";
    for entry in glob(pattern).expect("Failed to read glob pattern") {
        if let Ok(path) = entry {
            if let Some(file_name) = path.file_name().and_then(|name| name.to_str()) {
                let file_name_normalized = normalize(file_name);
                if file_name_normalized.contains(&normalized) {
                    println!("{:?}", path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn normalize(text: &str) -> String {
    let normalized = text
        .replace(&['：', ':', '-', '—', '_', ',', '.', '"'][..], "")
        .to_lowercase()
        .split_whitespace()
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>()
        .join(" ");
    normalized
}
```

Output:

```
"/home/alex/Downloads/papers/Hello：world-    This   is  a  test   string._,\".pdf"
```

It works fine, but I'm wondering if I can flatten all those nested if let statements and if statements?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2ddce59b434fce2c7627c910e27aabe7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flatten the nested ifs by using the common [guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computer_science%29) pattern, that is `continue` whenever something does not apply instead of nesting, that gets helped further by the recent [`let else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/flow_control/let_else.html) construct:

```rust
use glob::glob;

fn main() {
    let text = "Hello：world-    This   is  a  test   string._,\"";
    let normalized = normalize(text);
    let pattern = "/home/alex/Downloads/papers/*";
    for entry in glob(pattern).expect("Failed to read glob pattern") {
        let Ok(path) = entry else { continue; };
        let Some(file_name) = path.file_name().and_then(|name| name.to_str()) else { continue; };
        let file_name_normalized = normalize(file_name);
        if file_name_normalized.contains(&normalized) {
            println!("{:?}", path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh that's nice, I didn't know about let-else.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `?` operator and `filter_map` if you prefer functional style.

```
use glob::glob;

fn main() {
    let text = "Hello：world-    This   is  a  test   string._,\"";
    let normalized = normalize(text);
    let pattern = "/home/alex/Downloads/papers/*";
    glob(pattern)
        .expect("Failed to read glob pattern")
        .filter_map(|path| {
            let path = path.ok()?;
            let file_name = path.file_name()?.to_str()?;
            normalize(file_name).contains(&normalized).then_some(path)
        })
        .for_each(|path| println!("{:?}", path));
}
```

An advantage of this approach is easier to extract helper functions than `let-else` approach.

```
use glob::{glob, GlobError};
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    let text = "Hello：world-    This   is  a  test   string._,\"";
    let normalized = normalize(text);
    let pattern = "/home/alex/Downloads/papers/*";
    glob(pattern)
        .expect("Failed to read glob pattern")
        .filter_map(file_name_contains(&normalized))
        .for_each(|path| println!("{:?}", path));
}

fn file_name_contains(str: &str) -> impl FnMut(Result<PathBuf, GlobError>) -> Option<PathBuf> + '_ {
    move |path| {
        let path = path.ok()?;
        let file_name = path.file_name()?.to_str()?;
        normalize(file_name).contains(str).then_some(path)
    }
}
```